# href in attr not working

Tags: jquery

Trying to swap images once a radio button is selected with the 2nd image being a link. The images are swapping successfully onclick, however the second image is not linking.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#chkImg').click(function() {
      if($('#chkImg:checked').val()!=null) {
          $('#imgImage').attr({ src: 'circle.png' , href: 'http://www.google.com' })
      }
  })
})
</script>

<input type="radio" name="chkImg" id="chkImg">
<img id="imgImage" name="imgImage" src="square.png"> </p>
```

Comment: img element doesn't have `href` attribute, you need to wrap it in a tag.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `<a>` tag for a `href` attribute to work.

```
$('#imgImage').attr({ src: 'circle.png' })
  .wrap('<a href="http://www.google.com">');
```

Comment: Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dnBR/)

Answer (score 0):

href is only valid inside an `<a />` tag. If you want your `<img />` tag to be clickable, you might want to try redirecting using javascript:

```
$('#imgImage')
  .attr({ src: 'circle.png' })
  .click(function() { window.location = 'http://www.google.com' });
```